# Netlogo - how to show the final sum of ticks passed

Tags: timer, simulation, netlogo

I'm currently working on a simulation where i've programmed turtles to move faster when they reach a specific number of ticks. Given this reason i have to reset the ticks to make the command go over and over again. What i want to do is to see the final sum of ticks that has been run through the entire simulation but with the reset tick command, i can only see how many ticks has been run since the last time i used the move command on my turtles. This makes it impossible for me to use the "monitor" in my interface to show ticks. So how do i see the final count of ticks that has been run since i started the simulation, and not only since the last time it reset the ticks.

Answer (score 0):

1. To do what you describe, you could create a global variable (say, `tickTotal`), increment it each tick, and add a monitor to the interface.
2. But what you should do instead is stop resetting ticks.  Instead, use the `mod` command to control your cyclical response of turtle movement to the tick count.

Comment: What would the code look like to increment it each tick? for now i have defined: 
globals [tickTotal]

to setup
set tickTotal

end

But i dont know what the code for letting ticktotal add a value for each tick will look like?